# Google "latest" or realtime search of Twitter statuses

Tags: twitter, google-search

Some time ago there was an advanced type of Google search, accessible via left panel (more search tools and time period limiting). The results of `latest` was almost realtime, and there was an autoupdater (new statuses were printed at top).

Now I can't find this feature. How can I do a realtime Twitter search? The search.twitter.com asks me to refresh:

```
 8 more results since you started searching. Refresh to see them.
```

Comment: I remember reading that Google had to stop the twitter searches... Although I could be wrong...

Comment: @Kyle is right. This isn't available anymore; the agreement has expired and won't be renewed in its current form: http://www.dailytech.com/article.aspx?newsid=22070

Comment: As for realtime searches, plenty of 3rd party clients do that.  (I won't post an answer because this question isn't really ontopic for SU.)

Answer (score 5):

Google "canceled" their Twitter realtime search recently:
http://blog.tweetsmarter.com/twitter-search/google-contract-with-twitter-expires-suspends-realtime-search/

Maybe they want to "push" Google+? ;)

Comment: As I understand it, it was a contractual issue. Though I doubt any such decision between two such behemoths could be boiled down to such simplistic conditions.

Comment: So, what realtime twitter search with autoupdate (push) can you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with TweetDeck. Create a custom column for your search and it will update in real time.